Logging service in OpenSearch Dashboard
I’m using OS Dashboards 2.12.0 at the moment. I’m trying to configure the logging service policy that rotates the file every given interval of time.
For example:
In Kibana
logging:
root:
appenders:
- rolling-file
appenders:
rolling-file:
type: rolling-file
fileName: “/data/logs/kibana/kibana-%i.log”
policy:
type: time-interval
interval: 10s
modulate: true
strategy:
type: numeric
max: 100
layout:
type: json

I tried to apply the same settings in OpenSearch Dashboard, but, it didn’t work.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated
